# Stack multiple images in semitransparent layers with Imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

What is a simple way to stack multiple (~ 10) PNG images as layers with the same transparency that's less than 100% using one or two `Imagemagick` commands?

The source images are the same size and are not transparent.

I tried several variants of this:

`composite -dissolve 50 in1.png in2.png -alpha Set out.png`

The best that I could get is one image stacked as semintransparent against another that is solid. No success with wildcards. I'm a casual user of `Imagemagick`.  I guess that I could write a script or a simple program that would do what I want for multiple images, but there may be a simple way to do it in `Imagemagick` already, and that's what I'm hoping to find.

Modifying the images would be okay, e.g. setting the alpha to some value using a command that takes a wildcard and then stacking them.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this in Imagemagick, depending upon what you are really trying to achieve. Using version 6.9.9.12 Q16 Mac OSX.

`I have corrected the commands to fix a typo in the arguments of the third example and included Xenoid's suggested weights to make the first example below become equivalent to the other two so that each result is the same as averaging the images.`

Input Image:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Method 1: Using alpha channel

```
convert checks.jpg \( lena2.jpg -alpha set -channel alpha -evaluate multiply 0.5 \) \( zelda3.jpg -alpha set -channel alpha -evaluate multiply 0.3333 \) -flatten result0.png
```

[image]

Method 2: Equal averaging (-evaluate-sequence mean)

```
convert checks.jpg lena2.jpg zelda3.jpg -evaluate-sequence mean result1.png
```

[image]

Method 3: Weighted averaging (-poly)

```
convert checks.jpg lena2.jpg zelda3.jpg -poly "0.33333,1 0.33333,1 0.33333,1" result2.png
```

The first number of a pair is the weight and the second number is the exponent, so here it will be 1. A value of 2 would weight squares.

[image]

Comment: Possibly not a bug, if you stack images and want equal contribution to the output, their opacity should be 1/N, N being their position from the bottom of the stack (bottom is 100% opacity, then 50%, 33%,25%, etc...)

Comment: See my EDIT in the post. I had a typo and the last pair of numbers should be 0.33333,1 and not 0.33333.1. With that change the last two images are the same. In the first example, I did not use equal weights just the show the method to use transparency. I did not know if he wanted equal weights including the first image or not. Xenoid has pointed out how to make them have equal weights since the transparency compounds with each new image.

Comment: @xenoid Correct - there is a presentation of this on the *"Cambridge in Colour"* website here and some other material of interest to photographers... http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-averaging-noise.htm

Comment: The technique Xenoid suggests with transparency is called a running (moving) average. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Comment: @flw42 IMHO it is just a coincidence that Moving Average and this produce similar formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Averaging was the way to do this:

```
convert <file names or pattern> -evaluate-sequence mean averaged.png
```

Found the answer here:

http://jamesbritt.com/posts/imagemagick-image-averaging.html